# ENCODING_ERR Javascript Blob with Ionic file plugin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-native

Can you tell me why this code is not working?

Note: [file is native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

```
var blob = new Blob(["This is my blob content"], { type: "text/plain" });

    this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'myletter.txt', blob, { replace: true })
      .then(() => {
        //code
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err); //it comes to here
      });
```

It gives this exception:

```
FileError
code : 5
message : "ENCODING_ERR"
__proto__  : Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue here. That was due to this path `this.file.dataDirectory`.

*Solution:* Use this instead `this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory`